# Button for JSON formatting in Kate

Tags: linux, kate

I usually pretty print in JSON using Filter text plugin and jc utility (info: https://blog.philliptaylor.net/easily-format-json-using-kde-kate-easy-technique/)

I would like to have a button on the toolbar for that. In other words, the button should run `jq '.'` on the current text content. Is there a way to do that?